# How to create a smooth scrolling effect on the full page ?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, smooth-scrolling

I would like to know how to do a smooth scrolling effect on a full page like on this website : http://www.melville-design.com/le-concept/ or on this page : http://manos.malihu.gr/repository/custom-scrollbar/demo/examples/full_page_demo.html

The effect that I'm looking for is the easing effect or the "lerp effect"  of all the elements when I scroll up or down...

Does it exist a plugin for this effect ?

Thanks for your answers.

Comment: Melville design is using Greensock's TweenMax: http://greensock.com/tweenmax That's where i'd start

Comment: You probably want [something like this - scrollmagic](http://scrollmagic.io); one page scroll effects. In fact, that is what the first site (Melville) you linked **is using.** The second link you provided does not seem at all related to the first, it's simply a javascript scrollbar prettifier. I am not sure if we are supposed to know what the "lerp effect" is, but I've never heard of it and don't know what it means.

Comment: Thks you for the answers, in fact I'm looking for the ease effect which follows the element when I scroll, not the effect which shows the elements. For example, when I scroll... all the elements move a little bit with beautiful fluidity depending on the direction I scroll.

Thanks you ! 

(sorry for my english..)

Answer (score 0):

Hi the second page uses this script jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js, so it is jquery plugin

here you have the Page that show how to use it.

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/